# How can i store images directly to application gallery with out storing in Phone Gallery??

Tags: android, image-gallery

How can i store images directly to application gallery with out storing in Phone Gallery??

In my application 1 want to store image directly to my application gallery??

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you don't want to store in phone gallery?? I mean what's problem in that?

Comment: you can create a hidden folder and store images there for your application, and as u know from where u have to get images you can show them in your gallery.

Comment: @dreamcoder
Ok.
Then how can i store image in both application gallery and phone gallery?
The main problem is in my application gallery shows only the images taken from my application, I don't want to see all images in gallery.

Comment: @ mak_just4anything .
Then how can i store image taken from phone camera to that folder?

Comment: you have to make a custom camera application rather than using default phone camera, create a cameraview take a picture and store them into directory you want

Comment: @mak_just4anything.
Do u have any sample code for custom camera application?

Answer (score 0):

Create a cameraActivity in your application take a picture from there store into a folder which will be hidden so the default gallery application can not find images from the hidden folder and then when you start your application get images from there show them in your gallery. this link will provide you how to create cameraview for your application. [How to write an Android camera app](http://boundarydevices.com/blogs/how-to-write-an-android-camera-app)